# Diff between isset() and empty() in php

Tags: php, mysql, isset

I want to check whether monday is a holiday,if yes assign the value to $ts else go to tuesday.

```
  if (isset($list->hours_from_MON)) {
            $ts = $list->hours_from_MON;

        } else  (isset($list->hours_from_TUE)) {
            $ts = $list->hours_from_TUE;
```

The data in database is like {"hours_from_Mon":"","hours_from_Tue":"2am to 5pm"}

```
Here in the above case it should take ts as 2am to 5pm,but it is accepting "",i think i should use  

    if (!empty($list->hours_from_MON)) {
            $ts = $list->hours_from_MON;          

        } else  (!empty($list->hours_from_TUE)) {
            $ts = $list->hours_from_TUE;


   So that it will go to tue if,mon has no value.Am i right?Can some one help me.
```

Answer (score 1):

- [isset()](http://php.net/isset) will return TRUE if the variable exists and has value other than null or false
- [empty()](http://php.net/empty) will check if the variable is considered empty.

You can use [empty()](http://php.net/empty) without checking if the variable is set and it will not raise a warning.

The following things are considered to be empty:

```
"" (an empty string)
0 (0 as an integer)
0.0 (0 as a float)
"0" (0 as a string)
NULL
FALSE
array() (an empty array)
$var; (a variable declared, but without a value)
```

Comment: Thefore to check whether "hours_from_MON" is exists or not, i must use isset?

Comment: If hours_from_MON is always there and the value is changing between an empty string and a valid value, you should use empty.

Comment: ok but some times i may not even find  hours_from_MON,in this case if i use empty its working

Comment: because empty() will check if the var is set too. And if it's not, it will not raise a warning.

Comment: [Here](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php)'s a handy chart.